# Using one grep operation instead of two?

Tags: perl

Is there an efficient way to use `grep` in the following command that I am running, since I want to use only Perl's `grep`?

```
@found = grep { !/$IP/ } `$SSH $IPs[0] netstat -Aan | /bin/grep 1010`;
```

Basically, I am connecting to a fileserver, executing `netstat` command and grep IP addresses containing 1010. Then on this output I need to use `grep` to find a specific IP address.
Can this be done somehow using only one Perl command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can do this:

```
@found = grep { /1010/ && !/$IP/ } `$SSH $IPs[0] netstat -Aan`;
```

The condition you use in `grep` can be not just an arbitrary expression, but even a full block of code if need be.